# .NET Webbrowser Class xlink support for base64 images

Tags: html, .net, webbrowser-control, xlink

The following xhtml file is an exact copy of an epub cover page I'm loading into the WebBrowser Control (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6.aspx).

I would like to know why the .NET Web Browser class doesn't support xlink:href attributes.

Changing `<image width="600" height="900" xlink:href="cover.jpeg"/>` to `<image width="600" height="900" src="cover.jpeg"/>` works.

Short of writing a replace RegEx, do I have any alternatives? I would like to keep the HTML in it's native format.

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="calibre:cover" content="true"/>
        <title>Cover</title>
        <style type="text/css" title="override_css">
            @page {padding: 0pt; margin:0pt}
            body { text-align: center; padding:0pt; margin: 0pt; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 900" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <image width="600" height="900" xlink:href="cover.jpeg"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The WebBrowser  control is precisely Internet Explorer. The question is whether IE supports SVG out of the box. Have you tried browsing to that page in IE?

Comment: I was unaware this. I have tried everything but IE. Thanks for the input. This is the information I needed to further research the issue.